# How do I SIMPLY connect google docs and google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

```
myFunction(e){
var Name = e.values[1];
DocumentApp.create("Test");
DocumentApp.appendParagraph("hello" + Name);
DocumentApp.saveAndClose;
}
```

This is how simple I want it. "Name" is pulled from a sheet that is generated from a form and "Name" is inputted after form generates its data, upon edit

---

1. I am brand new to this. I mimicked the auto responder for when you get a form response, and "myFunction(e)" was name of function.
2. I would think bound to spreadsheet. Path from beginning to end: input data to form>collect data on spreadsheet>edit spreadsheet, add more data>create simple letter using most of data collected. Sample letter

`DocumentApp....appendParagragh("dear " + Name + "\n\n I like your " + Product + ". Are you interested in selling?")`.

There is an error related to "var Name = e.values[1];"

> "TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: Ive generated auto response emails from form data.

Comment: Ive created new doc using script. Im having trouble merging the 2 is all

Comment: Where is your script, bounded to a doc or spreadsheet or stand-alone? How are you calling your function? What is the value of `e`? If you are getting an error add it textually.

Comment: 1. I am brand new to this. I mimicked the auto responder for when you get a form response, and "myFunction(e)" was name of function. 2. I would think bound to spreadsheet. Path from beginning to end: input data to form>collect data on spreadsheet>edit spreadsheet, add more data>create simple letter using most of data collected. Sample letter DocumentApp....appendParagragh("dear " + Name + "\n\n I like your " + Product + ". Are you interested in selling?"). There is an error related to "var Name = e.values[1];" "TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: It looks that you are trying to do a "mail merge" app and asking about the whole flow makes the question too broad for this site. Try to make your question to be specific about one operation or programming issue. If you need help with several flow parts / issues post each one on separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting occurred because you tried to run your function using the Run button on the Google Apps Script editor as the function has `e` as parameter but it only gets an object automatically when it's called from a trigger.

A couple of related Q&A

- [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)
- [Getting TypeError in onFormSubmit trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17984230/1595451)
- [How do I resolve this "TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")" based on the context below?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24944086/1595451)

---

In order to get a value from a spreadsheet by using Google Apps Script we could use Class SpreadsheetApp. Example

The following script works on a bounded to spreadsheet script project.

```
function getName(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
  var name = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(name);
}
```

Comment: What does logger.log do? And will that A1 change on edit?

Comment: @RichardFullem Reggarding Logger.log see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#logging_custom_messages

Comment: Regarding the second question please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: So if I just put .getrange('A') and set my trigger to upon edit would that use the new data added in column A?

Comment: @RichardFullem 'A' is not a valid cell/range reference.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 4, file "Code")...very confused

Comment: @RichardFullem Assuming that you are using the code in my answer on a bounded to spreadsheet script project, your spreadsheet should have a sheet named 'Sheet1' in order to work. Maybe you should have to read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Fixed that problem now I just need to be able to change a1 to a2 or a-cell that I edit/change(automatically). The way i want it set up is: where i start with inputing data a1 then a2 then a3 but know that if any complications with a row that i can skip and comeback.

Comment: myFunction(e){name = e.value[1]}      why does this work when I do auto response mail but not on creating a document?

Comment: @RichardFullem I explained that on the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @RichardFullem I added a couple of related Q&A about the same error.

Comment: Sry im sick and not comprehending very well today. I do appreciate putting in the time to help me.